# Why is "there are the answers on the website" incorrect?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

> There are **the** answers on the website

I know this sentence is incorrect, but I don't understand why. This is from a conversation I had about a homework assignment. The questions for the homework assignment were on a website. So "there are the answers on the website" was said, but I know it is wrong.

I don't need help finding a correct wording, I just need help understanding why the original one is wrong.

I doubt the *first definite article* there.

Comment: "There are answers on the website" is fine, but "there answers are on the website" would be wrong too.

Comment: The title does not match either of the examples.

Comment: Those are correct versions, not examples. I was trying to show I don't need help fixing it. I just don't understand why the version in the title is wrong. I removed them to make it clearer.

Comment: You say you don't need help correcting the sentence, but the first suggestion from your original post was wrong. Given the context you've now provided, the correct wording is "The answers are on the website", though the second of your original suggestions "There are answers on the website" is also OK (although it doesn't necessarily mean that *all* of the answers are available on the website).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. *There  are the answers on the website* is a grammatical sentence.

Comment: This link helps you https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/it-and-there .

Comment: It is clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: Would you give us the exact question that this is an answer to - on its own it isn't obviously ungrammatical, but in a different context it might be. From [BBC World Service - it and there as preparatory subjects](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv182.shtml) : Note that when the subject in question has already been identified or there is no doubt that it exists, there is no need to use this structure. It would sound unnatural: _~ Yes, Brian is waiting for me outside. (NOT: There is Brian waiting for me outside.)_

Comment: Sorry, I still wasn't very clear. This sentence itself is not a homework question. There is a homework assignment. The answers for it are on a website. That's the context for "There are the answers on the website" - trying to explain that the answers for the homework assignment are on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [BBC World Service article](http://www.grammar.cl/Present/ThereIsThereAre.htm) on 'it' and 'there' may help explain it.

The way I understand the situation, you were talking about a homework assignment (which you already had the questions for) and someone said

> There are **the** answers on the website.

and we know that is wrong, but it's not really clear why it's wrong.

When we use *there + be + noun phrase*, we are saying something exists (or doesn't exist when we use the negative). We use indefinite articles, pronouns, or determiners with this form. For example,

> There is **some** milk in the fridge.
>   There is **a** clue in the library.
>   There are bats in the belfry!  (we don't know how many, but it seems like a lot!)
>   There is **something** coming and I think it wants to hurt us! (to paraphrase a character in a video game).

When we know that the subject exists because we've already identified it, like "**the** answers to the homework assignment", we don't use this form. I don't have to tell you **the** answers exist, because you already know they do if we're using the definite article. So, we would say:

> The answers are on the website.

We could also say

> There are **some** answers on the website.

or

> Are there **any** answers on the website?

but not

> *Are **there the** answers on the website?

Answer (score -2):

> There are the answers on the website

Yes this does not read well. If this is a homework question then I won't tell you the final answer :) But reading the below rules should help you determine the correct phrasing.

[When to Use Articles Before Nouns](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-use-articles-before-nouns)

1. Nouns That **Need** Determiners: Countable Singular Nouns such as cat in "*the* cat crossed *the* road"
2. Nouns That **Don't Need** Determiners: Proper Nouns such as the name Catherine in "Cat crossed the road"
3. Nouns That **Don't Need** Determiners: Plural Nouns such as cat in "cats cross roads"

And then applying the rules to the posted phrase

> the answers

See rule 3 for determiner application, "answers" is plural.

> the website

See rule 1 for determiner application, this is grammatically correct.

Comment: 'The answers to the test are on the website' is grammatical, so stating plural nouns don't need determiners isn't helpful. You really should provide a complete answer and not just list a bunch of rules without explaining how to apply them. See [Policy on homework questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1153/9161) on [meta] for an explanation on why it's OK to answer this question even though it is a homework question.

Comment: It's not so much a matter of "correct vs. incorrect" as a matter of shades of meaning.  "There are answers" = there are some nonspecific answers.  "There are the answers"  = there are some specific answers to which we've already referred.  No different from saying "cats crossed the road" vs. "the cats crossed the road."

Comment: Sorry, this is not a homework assignment. I was discussing a homework assignment, but this sentence itself is not from the homework.

Comment: @ColleenV.  I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, could you please provide an example?   Taking the "plural nouns don't need determiners", the application is simply that if you have a plural, don't put a determiner.  That's how to apply the rule and examples are listed.  The question cited a specific determiner (the) and so the rules around when to apply the the (excuse the repeated word) are exactly what the requester needs to know?

Comment: What I'm really objecting to is: `If this is a homework question then I won't tell you the answer` Making the learner guess the right answer instead of telling them what it is and explaining it is not a good answer. ''The answers to the test are on the website' - is that grammatical according to those rules you listed without any explanation of how to apply them? Answers is plural in that sentence and has 'the' in front of it, so I think a learner would assume from your answer that the sentence wasn't grammatical when it is. I'm not the source of the down-vote by the way.

Comment: Ah right I get it cheers.  Edited with additional help, but having guided my own children through english at school, I just can't bring myself to go any further into the answer, answering the question directly will only help in this instance but learning the rules will help answer all questions.  The rules and guidance cited is be sufficient for future readers to work out the answer.